# Spring boot use maven native dependency

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

I'm using a library provided by our HSM manufacturer but I'm having issues to "integrate" it in our Maven Java project.

I successfully add them to our maven artifactory and I added 3 dependencies to the pom.xml, one for the so file, one for the dll file and one for the jar file.

Everything seems to be downloaded correctly to my local Maven repository and I can use the classes within my code but I'm having 2 issues:

- I can't figure out how to package it in my jar file to make it works inside a docker image.
- When I try to run it from Intellij I'm getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError because it's not in my java.library.path but as it's in my pom.xml and as a dependency it should find it right?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which Java version do you use? Which Spring Boot Version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: @baskwo please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220467/104891.

Comment: I saw it but I think it's not quite what I want.
I'll try it back monday and get you guys an update after :)

Comment: @baskwo you can't load the native libraries from inside the jar, you will have to write the code which unpacks the library from the jar into some temp location and loads it from there, see how [JNA library](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) manages it.

Comment: So the better for me would be to have the dll and so file inside a folder and modify the java.library.path to point to that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CrazyCoder pointed out, the simplest way is to have maven to extract those native libraries and then modify the environment to use that folder.